# Problem with embedded fonts on input field

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

I'm trying to embed a font using css on in my flex project via CSS:

```
@font-face {
    src: url("/slimCurves.ttf");
    fontFamily: SlimCurves;
    embedAsCFF: true;
    font-weight:normal;
}


.slimCurves
{
    fontFamily: SlimCurves;
    fontLookup: embeddedCFF;
    fontSize: 15px;
}
```

When I try to apply the style to a text input field the input field looses its existing style, but doesn't seem to inherit the custom one.

```
<s:TextInput width="100%" fontSize="33" text="test" styleName="slimCurves"/>
```

If I apply the same style to a label, the label shows the text in the custom font as would be expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this had something to do with the selected theme. Selecting a different template seems to have resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problems is due to the fact that Buttons Text is by default in BOLD.
You are creating only the normal Font and not the bold one.

I usually use this code:

```
@font-face{
   src: url("FONT.TTF");
   fontFamily: DAX2;
   font-weight:normal;
}
@font-face{
   src: url("FONT.TTF");
   fontFamily: DAX2;
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

Kind regards,
Claudio

Comment: I actually tried this also, to no avail. My problem seemed to be related to using the default adobe spark theme in adobe flash builder 4.5. Switching to a different theme seemed to resolve this issue. Still not sure why this would be the case though.